# How to create choropleth map in R studio from a data frame extracted from XML

Tags: xml, r, ggplot2, choropleth

(totally new to R) I have downloaded an XML file to use in R to create a choropleth map from the data. I am using US flu data. From my research I understand that I needed to make that XML file a data frame for R to read. So I have done that. When I view my data frame I get all the XML formatting with it.  The question I have is how do I take the information that I need and extract it to create a map? At this point I am getting errors on even plotting the data. I have looked high and low for this information and I haven't found it as of yet.

```
 setwd("C:/Users/Steven/Downloads/Map_Final")
> library (XML)
> library(ggplot2)
> library(maps)
> library(plyr)
> library(mapproj)
> map('state')
> 
> xmlfile=xmlParse("flu.xml")
> 
> class(xmlfile)
[1] "XMLInternalDocument" "XMLAbstractDocument"
> ggplot(xmlfile)
Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class XMLInternalDocumentXMLAbstractDocument
> xmltop = xmlRoot(xmlfile) #gives content of root
> 
> class(xmltop)#"XMLInternalElementNode" "XMLInternalNode" "XMLAbstractNode"
[1] "XMLInternalElementNode" "XMLInternalNode"        "XMLAbstractNode"       
> 
> xmlName(xmltop) #give name of node, PubmedArticleSet
[1] "timeperiod"
> 
> xmlSize(xmltop) #how many children in node, 19
[1] 54
> 
> xmlName(xmltop[[1]]) #name of root's children
[1] "state"
> 
> xmltop[[1]]
<state>
  <abbrev>ME</abbrev>
  <color>No Activity</color>
  <label>No Activity</label>
</state> 
> 
> xmltop[[2]]
<state>
  <abbrev>NH</abbrev>
  <color>Local Activity</color>
  <label>Local Activity</label>
</state> 
> 
> ggplot(xmltop)
Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class XMLInternalElementNodeXMLInternalNodeXMLAbstractNode
> xmltop[[2]]
<state>
  <abbrev>NH</abbrev>
  <color>Local Activity</color>
  <label>Local Activity</label>
</state> 
> 
> xmltop[[2]]
<state>
  <abbrev>NH</abbrev>
  <color>Local Activity</color>
  <label>Local Activity</label>
</state> 
> 
> birdflu=ldply(xmlToList("flu.xml"), data.frame)
> ggplot(birdflu)
Error: No layers in plot
> View(birdflu)
```

XML File:

```
<timeperiod number="40" year="2014" subtitle="Week Ending October 11, 2014- Week 40">
<state>
<abbrev>ME</abbrev>
<color>No Activity</color>
<label>No Activity</label>
</state>
<state>
<abbrev>NH</abbrev>
<color>Local Activity</color>
<label>Local Activity</label>
</state>
<state>
<abbrev>VT</abbrev>
<color>Sporadic</color>
<label>Sporadic</label>
</state>
<state>
<abbrev>MA</abbrev>
<color>Sporadic</color>
<label>Sporadic</label>
</state>
<state>
<abbrev>RI</abbrev>
<color>No Activity</color>
<label>No Activity</label>
</state>
<state>
<abbrev>CT</abbrev>
<color>Sporadic</color>
<label>Sporadic</label>
</state>
<state>
<abbrev>NY</abbrev>
<color>Sporadic</color>
<label>Sporadic</label>
</state>
<state>
<abbrev>NJ</abbrev>
<color>Sporadic</color>
<label>Sporadic</label>
</state>
<state>
<abbrev>PR</abbrev>
<color>Regional</color>
<label>Regional</label>
</state>
<state>
<abbrev>VI</abbrev>
<color>Sporadic</color>
<label>Sporadic</label>
</state>
<state>
<abbrev>PA</abbrev>
<color>Sporadic</color>
<label>Sporadic</label>
</state>
<state>
<abbrev>DE</abbrev>
<color>No Activity</color>
<label>No Activity</label>
</state>
<state>
<abbrev>MD</abbrev>
<color>No Activity</color>
<label>No Activity</label>
</state>
<state>
<abbrev>DC</abbrev>
<color>Sporadic</color>
<label>Sporadic</label>
</state>
<state>
<abbrev>VA</abbrev>
<color>Sporadic</color>
<label>Sporadic</label>
</state>
<state>
<abbrev>WV</abbrev>
<color>No Activity</color>
<label>No Activity</label>
</state>
<state>
<abbrev>NC</abbrev>
<color>Sporadic</color>
<label>Sporadic</label>
</state>
<state>
<abbrev>SC</abbrev>
<color>Sporadic</color>
<label>Sporadic</label>
</state>
<state>
<abbrev>GA</abbrev>
<color>Sporadic</color>
<label>Sporadic</label>
</state>
<state>
<abbrev>FL</abbrev>
<color>Sporadic</color>
<label>Sporadic</label>
</state>
<state>
<abbrev>KY</abbrev>
<color>No Activity</color>
<label>No Activity</label>
</state>
<state>
<abbrev>TN</abbrev>
<color>No Activity</color>
<label>No Activity</label>
</state>
<state>
<abbrev>AL</abbrev>
<color>Local Activity</color>
<label>Local Activity</label>
</state>
<state>
<abbrev>MS</abbrev>
<color>No Activity</color>
<label>No Activity</label>
</state>
<state>
<abbrev>OH</abbrev>
<color>Sporadic</color>
<label>Sporadic</label>
</state>
<state>
<abbrev>IN</abbrev>
<color>No Activity</color>
<label>No Activity</label>
</state>
<state>
<abbrev>IL</abbrev>
<color>No Activity</color>
<label>No Activity</label>
</state>
<state>
<abbrev>MI</abbrev>
<color>Sporadic</color>
<label>Sporadic</label>
</state>
<state>
<abbrev>WI</abbrev>
<color>Sporadic</color>
<label>Sporadic</label>
</state>
<state>
<abbrev>MN</abbrev>
<color>Sporadic</color>
<label>Sporadic</label>
</state>
<state>
<abbrev>AR</abbrev>
<color>Sporadic</color>
<label>Sporadic</label>
</state>
<state>
<abbrev>LA</abbrev>
<color>Sporadic</color>
<label>Sporadic</label>
</state>
<state>
<abbrev>OK</abbrev>
<color>No Activity</color>
<label>No Activity</label>
</state>
<state>
<abbrev>TX</abbrev>
<color>Sporadic</color>
<label>Sporadic</label>
</state>
<state>
<abbrev>NM</abbrev>
<color>Sporadic</color>
<label>Sporadic</label>
</state>
<state>
<abbrev>IA</abbrev>
<color>No Activity</color>
<label>No Activity</label>
</state>
<state>
<abbrev>MO</abbrev>
<color>No Activity</color>
<label>No Activity</label>
</state>
<state>
<abbrev>NE</abbrev>
<color>No Activity</color>
<label>No Activity</label>
</state>
<state>
<abbrev>KS</abbrev>
<color>No Activity</color>
<label>No Activity</label>
</state>
<state>
<abbrev>ND</abbrev>
<color>Local Activity</color>
<label>Local Activity</label>
</state>
<state>
<abbrev>SD</abbrev>
<color>Sporadic</color>
<label>Sporadic</label>
</state>
<state>
<abbrev>MT</abbrev>
<color>No Activity</color>
<label>No Activity</label>
</state>
<state>
<abbrev>WY</abbrev>
<color>Sporadic</color>
<label>Sporadic</label>
</state>
<state>
<abbrev>CO</abbrev>
<color>Sporadic</color>
<label>Sporadic</label>
</state>
<state>
<abbrev>UT</abbrev>
<color>Sporadic</color>
<label>Sporadic</label>
</state>
<state>
<abbrev>AZ</abbrev>
<color>No Activity</color>
<label>No Activity</label>
</state>
<state>
<abbrev>NV</abbrev>
<color>No Activity</color>
<label>No Activity</label>
</state>
<state>
<abbrev>CA</abbrev>
<color>Sporadic</color>
<label>Sporadic</label>
</state>
<state>
<abbrev>HI</abbrev>
<color>Sporadic</color>
<label>Sporadic</label>
</state>
<state>
<abbrev>GU</abbrev>
<color>Widespread</color>
<label>Widespread</label>
</state>
<state>
<abbrev>ID</abbrev>
<color>No Activity</color>
<label>No Activity</label>
</state>
<state>
<abbrev>WA</abbrev>
<color>Sporadic</color>
<label>Sporadic</label>
</state>
<state>
<abbrev>OR</abbrev>
<color>Sporadic</color>
<label>Sporadic</label>
</state>
<state>
<abbrev>AK</abbrev>
<color>Sporadic</color>
<label>Sporadic</label>
</state>
</timeperiod>
```

Comment: I'm finding it _really_ difficult to believe you actually thought `ggplot` would know how to just plot a choropleth map from a random XML file.

Comment: Did you read the totally new to R part? I have worked a little with ggplot and figured if my data was ok to be plotted out that would be one way to try to get it to work.

Comment: Yep. Even with being new to R, even a cursory search on SO would have shown the basics of plotting a choropleth (I've written a few of the answers), enough to see what shape the XML should be transformed in. Is it the XML transformation you need more than the actual choropleth?

Comment: What I had done so far was take the data frame and only subset it to only be the state, color and label. My next step is to convert the entire dataframe to lowercase, merge my data with the map, and create it. R studio shows a table that looks exactly how I want the data from my new data frame, Im just having trouble getting from my data frame now to make it a map. So yes, i think i need the proper data more than creating the map. As long as I know the data i want will be displayed I should be good to go. That and converting it to lowercase df$region  = tolower(df$region); didnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic, annotated example below using built-in (ggplot) US map data. If you need the territories (which have more outbreaks it seems) you'll need to look at the other SO examples that show that (of which there are many).

```
library(xml2)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

# read in the XML file

flu <- read_xml("flu.xml")

# get data from it into data frame

flu_dat <- data_frame(id=flu %>% xml_find_all("//state/abbrev") %>% xml_text,
                      value=flu %>% xml_find_all("//state/color") %>% xml_text)

# for built-in (ggplot) map data we need names, not abbreviations

state_name <- state.name
names(state_name) <- state.abb

us <- map_data("state")

# convert abbrev to name; ensure ordered factor, filter by what the
# built-in plot has. NOTE that if you need the territories, you'll
# need to use another base map of which there are many examples on SO

flu_dat %>% 
  mutate(id=state_name[id],
         Level=factor(value, 
                      levels=c("No Activity", "Local Activity", 
                               "Sporadic", "Regional", "Widespread"),
                      ordered=TRUE)) %>% 
  filter(id %in% unique(us$region))-> flu_dat

us <- fortify(us, region="region")

# for theme_map convenience function
devtools::source_gist("33baa3a79c5cfef0f6df")

gg <- ggplot()
# plot outlines
gg <- gg + geom_map(data=us, map=us,
                    aes(x=long, y=lat, map_id=region, group=group),
                    fill="#ffffff", color="#7f7f7f", size=0.25)
# plot fills based on flu data
gg <- gg + geom_map(data=flu_dat, map=us,
                    aes(fill=Level, map_id=id),
                    color="#7f7f7f", size=0.25)
# manual fill scale showing all possible values on legend
gg <- gg + scale_fill_manual(values=c("#f2f0f7", "#dadaeb", "#bcbddc", 
                                      "#9e9ac8", "#756bb1"), drop=FALSE)
# a proper US projection
gg <- gg + coord_map("albers", lat0=39, lat1=45)
gg <- gg + theme_map()
gg <- gg + theme(legend.position="right")
gg
```

[image]

Comment: For some reason my map comes out blank with no colors or legend?